# Extend placeholder selector in Stylus

Tags: css, stylus

In Sass, I can `@extend` `%placeholder` selectors from any place of my selectors tree, such as:

```
.category {
  .category-dropdown {
    button {
      visibility: hidden;
      @extend %category-hovered-button;
    }
  }
  &:hover {
    %category-hovered-button {
      visibility: visible;
    }
  }
}
```

[Working on lib sass (v3.2.5)](http://www.sassmeister.com/gist/Grawl/a1ed08f86e678c79d759)

But in Stylus, I can't `@extend` similar way. *I think it's because of different nature of Stylus placeholder selectors.*

[image: Extending a placeholder selector in Stylus is not working the Sass way]

So how can I do this DRY thing in Stylus?

*Tried to replace `$` to `.`, and tried to move `&:hover` subtree before `.category-dropdown`.*

Comment: Maybe &:extend($catgiru-hovered-button) like less css.

Comment: Oh wait it should be ``@extend .category-hovered-button``

Comment: And % should be . below &:hover

Answer (score 3):

Here's a possible solution:

```
.category {
  $prefix = selector()
  hovered() {
      /{$prefix}:hover {selector('^[1..-1]')} {
        {block}
      }
    }
  }
  category-hovered-button() {
    +hovered() {
      +cache() {
        visibility: visible
      }
    }
  }

  .category-dropdown {
    button {
      visibility: hidden
      category-hovered-button()
    }
  }
  .category-other {
    a {
      visibility: hidden
      category-hovered-button()
    }
  }
}
```

Compiles into this:

```
.category .category-dropdown button {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.category:hover .category-dropdown button,
.category:hover .category-other a {
  visibility: visible;
}
.category .category-other a {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

It's probably not what you want, but it *does* keep things DRY.  As you said, Stylus's @extend behavior is simpler than Sass's.

Line 4 does nothing more than replace `.category` with `.category:hover`, while keeping things 100% DRY.  Here's how:

- [The `selector()` function](http://stylus-lang.com/docs/selectors.html#selector-bif) computes the current selector, optionally with some additional appended selectors.
- [`^[1..-1]`](http://stylus-lang.com/docs/selectors.html#ranges-in-partial-references) is a special slicing syntax, in this case omitting the first part of the selector. (`.category`)
- [The `/` prefix](http://stylus-lang.com/docs/selectors.html#root-reference) tells Stylus not to prefix the selector with any parent selectors.
- [`{}`](http://stylus-lang.com/docs/interpolation.html#selector-interpolation) performs interpolation.

Since `category-hovered-button` is a mixin, and you probably don't want duplicated CSS rules, I enabled caching with [`+cache()`](http://stylus-lang.com/docs/bifs.html#cachekeys)

Comment: Madness. But I like it.